# Return property of object in list in a seperate (but public) class

Tags: c#, list, properties

I haven't quite got the knowledge to be able to apply other solutions I've found for similar problems to mine, so apologies if anyone thinks I'm duplicating.

I'm fairly new to c# and constructing a simple trading game in a windows form.

In short what I would like to do is return the Description property of a list object when a cell in a dgv is clicked which contains the Name of that object.  The list is in a seperate public class by the way.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Commodity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsPerishable { get; set; }
        public bool IsIllegal { get; set; }

        public Commodity (int id, int cost, string name, string description, bool isPerishable, bool isIllegal)
        {
            ID = id;
            Cost = cost;
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
            IsPerishable = isPerishable;
            IsIllegal = isIllegal;

        }
    }
```

...

```
    public static class World
        {
        public static readonly List<Commodity> Commodities = new List<Commodity>();
        ...
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_TEA = 1;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_SPICES = 2;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_FISH = 3;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_SILK = 4;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_SLAVES = 5;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_NARCOTICS = 6;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_FRUIT = 7;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_MEAT = 8;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_BOOKS = 9;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_METAL= 10;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_COAL = 11;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_WEAPONS = 12;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_SUGAR_CANE= 13;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_MEDICINE = 14;
            public const int COMMODITY_ID_DEEDS = 15;
    ...
    static World()
            {
                 PopulateCommodities()
            }
    ...
    private static void PopulateCommodities()
            {
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_TEA, 25, "Tea", "Dried leaves that get boiled then drunk.", false, false));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_SPICES, 50, "Spices", "Individually wrapped though, not a secret blend of 13.", false, false));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_FISH, 35, "Fish", "Smells like fish.", true, false));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_SILK, 120, "Silk", "Luxurious material that makes really comfy pants.", false, false));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_SLAVES, 800, "Slaves", "Who doesn't want their own slave? Careful though, it's against the law to trade these in some places.", false, true));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_NARCOTICS, 2000, "Narcotics", "Substances that are dangerous and illegal - don't get caught buying or selling!", false, true));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_FRUIT, 400, "Fruit", "Exotic fruits from all over the world.  Good in smoothies.", true, false));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_MEAT, 750, "Meat", "Cured meat. Cured from what, though?", false, false));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_BOOKS, 1250, "Books", "First edition collectibles.  Don't get them wet.", false, false));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_METAL, 800, "Metal", "Construction materials.  For building with.", false, false));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_COAL, 1000, "Coal", "Black rocks that burn really well.", false, false));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_WEAPONS, 5000, "Weapons", "Guns and bombs and stuff. Illegal in some places.", false, true));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_SUGAR_CANE, 1500, "Sugar Cane", "Sweet!", true, false));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_MEDICINE, 7500, "Medicine", "Maybe these cured the meat?", false, false));
                Commodities.Add(new Commodity(COMMODITY_ID_DEEDS, 15000, "Deeds", "Title deeds to some prime land!", false, false));

            }
...

public static Commodity CommodityByID(int id)
        {
            foreach(Commodity commodity in Commodities)
            {
                if(commodity.ID == id)
                {
                    return commodity;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

... so thats how the information has been constructed.

```
 public partial class Plunder : Form
    {
... // The dgv is populated at this point.

private void dgvShopStock_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string chosenCell = dgvShopStock.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
            string chosenType = dgvShopStock.Columns[0].Name.ToString();
            //So far so good - chosenCell returns the contents and chosenType returns the column header as there are other types of object which can appear in this box - not important now.

            //Here's me trying IndexOf.  Returns a 'cannot convert string to Commodity' error.  I tried casting without success.
            int index = World.Commodities.IndexOf(chosenCell);


            //This attempts to construct the strings "World.CommodityByID" and the parameter for it of "World.COMMODITY_ID_BOOKS" in this case.  This was to attempt reflection instead but I dont fully understand it and don't know where to go from here.

            string methodName = "World." + chosenType + "ByID";
            string param = "World." + chosenType.ToUpper() + "_ID_" + chosenCell.ToUpper();

            Commodity returnedItem;
            MethodInfo chosenItem = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
            chosenItem.Invoke(this, param);
            rtbDescription.Text = returnedItem.Description;
        }
}
```

Sorry for the length of this, but I'mnot good at explaining my situation from the eyes of an outsider, so I thought it best to include relevant code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to my question per se as I was asking the wrong question, but here is what I did to achieve the desired result.

```
    foreach (Commodity commodity in World.Commodities)
    {
        if (chosenCell == commodity.Name)
        {
            rtb.Description = commodity.Description
        }
    }
```

Classic case of newbie overcomplificationising!